# how build an app that shows the shortest path between two points on google map using android studio

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I've been working on building a new app that shows the shortest path(s) between two points on google map using android studio but I was unsuccessful since I couldn't find any things on google or even the web page of android developers , I really appreciate it if some one could tell whether it is possible to build such an app or not 
I also tested this piece of code

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+latitude_source+","+longitude_source+"&daddr="+latitude_dest+","+longitude_dest));
    startActivity(i);
```

but it uses the built in google map on android devices to show the path(s) hence this is not what I want, I want to show the shortest path between two points on my own app that I am building , not using an other application.

Is it possible to use google map android api within your own app to show the shortest path(s) between two points?

Thanks 
Alfred

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android google map route between 2 point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554844/android-google-map-route-between-2-point)

Comment: Try to use this code:`Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+latitude_source+","+longitude_source+"&daddr="+latitude_dest+","+longitude_dest));
        startActivity(i);`